# Django urls.py template issue

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I am new to Django and just playing around with the code and features but I seem to be stuck (yes I have done the entire tutorial). For some reason my mysite/urls.py is not taking me to the right urls, actually it ONLY takes me to one template no matter what I do. Here is my urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *

# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('app.views',
    (r"^app/$",'index'),
    (r"^app/detail/$",'detail'),

    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

My app/views.py is:

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.http import HttpResponse

from mysite.app.models import Post,PostAdmin


def index(request):
    return render_to_response("app/link1.html")

def detail(request):
    return HttpResponse("You're looking at detail.")
```

I have a base.html template and link1 which `{% extends base.html %}`. But for some reason if I enter http://localhost:8000/app or http://localhost:8000/app/detail, I get the link1.html? Or even when I do http://localhost:8000/, I just get the link1.html. What could cause this? (Its probably something minor)

If I understand correctly shouldn't the url pattern with `(r^"app/detail/$",'detail')`, take me to the detail HttpResponse in views.py like the tutorial rather than a template?

Thank you

Comment: "just playing around with the code and features but I seem to be stuck".  Stop now.  Go to the tutorial.  Do the **entire** tutorial.  Please.  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/intro/tutorial01/

Comment: Don't add relevant facts in the comments.  **Update** the question to be complete and correct.  You -- as the original poster -- should not be writing comments.  You should be **updating** your question to be complete.  After updating your question, delete the comment.

Comment: Did you check the `ROOT_URLCONF` in `settings.py`? Plus, I don't know why `r'^$'` is working for you - it should be returning a `404`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have checked your code, it works just fine. I cannot replicate such error with your views and urls. Post your templates and directory structure to make sure they are fine too.

test result for /app/

> Hello link 1.

test result for /app/detail/

> You're looking at detail.

Comment: Thank you, it works now, don't know why it wasn't working before.